# wget ".listing: No such file or directory"

Tags: ftp, wget, host

I am trying to transfer a directory of one server to another (something I did two weeks ago) but now I am not sure why this is not working. I am using:

```
wget -nc -r ftp://user:password@host/directory/directory/
```

and then getting this:

```
Logging in as 'user'... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /directory/directory/directory ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.
host/dir/dir/dir: No such file or directoryhost/dir/dir/dir/.listing: No such file or directory
unlink: no such file or directory
```

What's going on?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you certain nothing on the server has changed?

Comment: just got it to work, i am not sure what i did though, maybe had a typo somewhere or something like that. Thanks for your fast reply anyways :)

Comment: Actually I think it was because I logged in with root user... could be that.

Comment: Related: ['No such file' when mirroring ftp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439279/21471)

Answer (score 25):

I recently got a `No such file or directory` error regarding the `.listing` file (similar to yours) and it turned out that the directory in which I was running `wget` was not writable.

Comment: This solved my problem too (had to add `sudo`), this is such an unorthodox error to see when the destination directory is not writable.

Comment: Very useful. Just saved me hours. Thanks.